# Delete string in between special characters in python

Tags: python, regex

I have string something like this

```
mystring = "CBS Network Radio Panel;\ntitle2 New York OCT13W4, Panel Weighting;\n*options; mprint ls=max mprint;\n\n****************************************out; asd; ***hg;"
```

I want to delete the string between * and ;
output should be

```
"CBS Network Radio Panel;\ntitle2 New York OCT13W4, Panel Weighting;\ mprint ls=max mprint;\n\n asd;"
```

I have tried this code

```
re.sub(r'[\*]*[a-z]*;', '', mystring)
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'\*[^;]*;', '', mystring)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Sq2jWS):

```
import re
mystring = "CBS Network Radio Panel;\ntitle2 New York OCT13W4, Panel Weighting;\n*options; mprint ls=max mprint;\n\n****************************************out; asd; ***hg;"
r = re.sub(r'\*[^;]*;', '', mystring)
print(r)
```

Output:

```
CBS Network Radio Panel;
title2 New York OCT13W4, Panel Weighting;
 mprint ls=max mprint;

 asd;
```

The `r'\*[^;]*;'` pattern matches a literal `*`, followed with zero or more characters other than `;` and then a `;`.